# Using share intent in Instagram. How to know is user actually shared or cancelled sharing activity?

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

Below is code;

```
 Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 shareIntent.setType("image/*");
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  Uri.parse("file://" + finalFile.getAbsolutePath()));
 shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share your Photo"),INSTA);
```

And below `onActivityResult` is not work;

```
if (requestCode==INSTA)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Here you do what you have to do.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"share successful...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"share unsuccessful...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**You can't.**

If the code, you've provided is not working, it means that *Instagram* doesn't return any result after sharing a picture. But even if they would return a result (for example, `RESULT_OK` it doesn't mean that the picture was actually shared).

The only way to get this information is to call instagram api and to check whether user posted new photo within (for example 1-2 mins) or not, but I think it's not possible without knowing the user :)